# Multiple background colours on 1 DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a `div`, and I would like to apply 2 backgrounds horizontally onto it using CSS3, but I can't figure it out, and so I would appreciate any help!

```
    background: blue top no-repeat 10%;
    background: yellow bottom no-repeat 10%;
```

I want the top half to be one color, and the bottom half to be a different colour.

I know it can be done quite easily with images, but I just can't figure out how to do this without using them.

Comment: you could set the `height: 50%` on two different div tags

Comment: You must mark an answer or else post your own, just an advice.. :)

Answer (score 10):

A gradient is a reasonably simple way to do this using CSS3 and only one `div`:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/8wH2F/

Yes, I lied. It's not very simple at all due to the myriad different vendor prefixed versions of the same thing that you need to use:

```css
div {
    background: #000fff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000fff 0%, #000fff 50%, #ffff00 50%, #ffff00 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#000fff), color-stop(50%,#000fff), color-stop(50%,#ffff00), color-stop(100%,#ffff00)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000fff 0%,#000fff 50%,#ffff00 50%,#ffff00 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000fff 0%,#000fff 50%,#ffff00 50%,#ffff00 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000fff 0%,#000fff 50%,#ffff00 50%,#ffff00 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #000fff 0%,#000fff 50%,#ffff00 50%,#ffff00 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

I generated the CSS [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), and removed the `filter` property since it will result in an actual gradient in IE6-9.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with IE7/8 though :/ Not even with CSS3PIE

Answer (score 4):

Another way to achieve this, apart from the gradients, is to use pseudo-element:

http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/S3LXB/

Add `position: relative` and some positive `z-index` to the element and the negative `z-index` to the pseudo-element, and it would be placed over the element's background, but under the element's content. And then you can position in just how you want.

This way is not as flexible as the one with gradients, but! You can for sure use the gradients for the pseudo-element and so achieve even more effects more easily.