# CSS3: multiple backgrounds. with colors?

Tags: css, background-image

if i try to apply multiple background images, works great:

```
.selector{  
     background-image: url(image1.png), url(image2.pnng);
     background-position: 0 -50px, 0 -100px;
}
```

the problem comes when i try

```
.selector{  
     background-color: blue, red;
     background-position: 0 -50px, 0 -100px;
}
```

that simply won't apply any background color at all..

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have more than one `background-color`.

You can either use images, or a CSS gradient to achieve your desired result.

Assuming your desired result is two colours meeting in the middle, [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686579/multiple-background-colours-on-1-div/7686618#7686618) for a gradient example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it.

You're trying to set the background color to two colors. How do you expect this to work? Multiple background images make sense as you can have transparent PNGs. But colours? You want to place a solid color on top of a solid color (so essentially overriding the previous color)? Background color applies to the whole area, so you can't shift it in space.

To answer your question, it's simply not possible to do that, unless you're thinking about gradients.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make much sense.  background-color: applies to the whole object.  It's like you're trying to set a background color to the images or something, but background-color doesn't work that way!