# centering a 900px wide element with background orange on the left and white on the right

Tags: html, css, colors, background, position

I have an element on my html page that i want to center on screen. This was easy. However: i want the background left of my element to by orange, while the background on the right should be white. I was thinking about a solution like:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner">
      <p>some content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
#middle {
  background-color: orange;
}
#inner {
  width: 900px;
}
```

The only thing missing in this is getting #inner to the center. Is there some way i can modify the padding or margin of #middle or #inner to get the desired result?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686579/multiple-background-colours-on-1-div

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903785/two-fixed-width-full-height-columns-with-seamless-transition-to-blank-space

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
#middle {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This only centers a div. I want the background on the left to be orange, and on the right to be white.

Comment: then create a background image with 2 colours

Comment: I did, but for users with large screens, this background abrubtly ends. Also, i prefer to do it with css if possible